# How to replace html content in dynamically created list using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamically-generated

I'm using jquery mobile to create a list view. This listview is created in a function when loading the page

```
$('#listStock').empty();
            $(data).find("people").each(function()
            {
                var _id = $(his).attr('id');
                var _name = $(this).attr('name');
                var _capacity = $(this).attr('capacity');
                $('#listStock').append('<li id="' + _name +'" data-theme="b"><a href="#detail" >'+_name+' '+_description+'<span class="ui-li-count">'+ _capacity+'</span>'+'</a></li>');
            });
```

I only want to create this list, but the capacity will change every minute. How can I change this part of the list dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

you must have the index of the changed capacity let _your_index in the list ,

```
      $('.ui-li-count').index(_your_index ).html(_your_capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$(document).bind('changeData', function(e){
    $('#listStock').empty();
    $(data).find("people").each(function(){
        var _id = $(this).attr('id');
        var _name = $(this).attr('name');
        var _capacity = $(this).attr('capacity');
        $('#listStock').append('<li id="' + _name +'" data-theme="b"><a href="#detail">'+_name+' '+_description+'<span class="ui-li-count">'+ _capacity+'</span>'+'</a></li>');
    });
    $('#listStock').listview('refresh');
});
```